# it gives me error called "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, callback

i'm getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table id="mytable">
  </table>

  <script>
    function myfun() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //call some function
        somefunction(i, function(err, result) {
            document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = "<tr><td>" + result[0] + "</td></tr>"
          }
        })
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The snippet gives a completely different error. Are you sure you have copied the code correctly?

Comment: This won't produce the type error because `myfun()` is not executed. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have mentioned works for me. See the below example.

```js
function somefunction(i, callback) {
  let result = ['item1', 'item2']
  return callback(null, [result[i]])
}

function myfun() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    somefunction(i, function(err, result) {
      document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML+ "<tr><td>" + result[0] + "</td></tr>"
    })
  }
}

myfun();
```

```html
<table id="mytable"></table>
```